# HTML5 video fullscreen button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-video

I found this html5 video player which supports youtube source. But it didn't have a fullscreen button, so I started to implement the full screen function.
My problem now is that on chrome or safari the video doesn't take 100% width (not really fullsize, i have a black gap on all sides).

I used this script:

```
$('.video-fullscreen-btn', player).bind('click', function(e){
        if (player.requestFullscreen) {
            player.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (player.msRequestFullscreen) {
            player.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (player.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            player.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (player.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            player.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    });
```

I also tried it with the css webkit

```
:-webkit-full-screen video {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

still not working. does someone have an idea why this is not working on chrome/safari?

The whole example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5PTv/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just due to the aspect ratio of the actual video content. If you look at the original youtube video it also has black bars either side of the video.

That is why the preload image looks pixelated because the image, which has the same aspect ratio as the video I assume, has been forced to take up the space.

If the video was to be the full width of the screen the top and bottom of the video would be clipped off. I assume you would rather have black bars on the side rather than clipping.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is aspect ratio you can control is with CSS **object-fit: fill;**
But this is only supported in Opera right now.

If the video element is using 100% of the screen this doesn't mean that the video-image it self will be stretched to fill the whole screen. You can opserve this by using the controls attribute on the video element and notice how the controls can be wider then the video-image.

Demo : http://netkoder.dk/netkoder/eksempler/eksempel0017.html